# Regex for a period not immediatly following a word in a list, without variable length lookbehind?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches periods **not** immediately followIing a word from a list.

I believe I need a lookahead or lookbehind assertion to do this, and I've tried:

`/(?!(mr|ms|mrs))\./u` and `/(?!(mr|ms|mrs)\.)\./u`

These both matches *all* the periods so it's not excluding periods after the words.

I also tried a lookbehind, which I believe is what I need:

`/(?<!(mr|ms|mrs))\./u`

but it looks like those have to be a fixed length because it won't compile: `preg_replace(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 15`.

Here's a few test cases, and the expected result when using preg replace to remove matches:

```
'Mr. Tom A. Suggins'     // Mr. Tom A Suggins
'Mrs.. Jane P Suggins, jr.'   // Mrs. Jane P Suggins, jr
'.Ms.. .Jane P. Suggins' // Ms. Jane P Suggins
```

Is there any way to do this in PHP without variable length lookbehind support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs in PCRE regex to fail/skip certain selected matches;

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?:Mrs?|Ms)\.(*SKIP)(*F)|\./', '', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EzVLtx/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to match those periods:

```
(?:mrs|m[rs])\.\K|\.
```

then replace them with nothing:

```
preg_repalce('~(?:mrs|m[rs])\.\K|\.~i', '', $content);
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/yRJHEg/1)

Comment: Plus one, since `\K` seems more succinct than `(*SKIP)(*F)`. I can only accept one answer though.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<!mr|ms|mrs)\./u
```

can be fixed with just a small change:

```
/(?<!m[rs])(?<!mrs)\./u
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s239wY/2)

Comment: It does. It's equivalent to `/(?<!(mr|ms|mrs))\./u` as you asked. If you want to make case-insensitive, you need to add `i`. If you want to find all matches, you need to add `g`. [Test](https://regex101.com/r/s239wY/2)

Comment: To be clear `(?<!mr|ms|mrs)\.` don't need to be fixed at all since an alternation of fixed branches is allowed in a lookbehind. The problem with `(?<!(mr|ms|mrs))\.` is only the additional capture group.